# Is it possible to create a Visualforce page with a standardListController on Invoice?

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, standardcontroller

I would like to use a visualforce page to send the ID's of selected Invoices to an external URL when a Custom button is clicked.

I created a custom button that redirects to a visualforce page, so far so good.
But when I try to write a simple visualforce page with a standard controller on Invoice, i get the error "Invoice does not exist" when trying to save the page.

[image]

Below is the page code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Invoice" recordSetVar="invoices">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/48.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var idArray = '{!selected}'.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ", "").split(',');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (!!idArray && idArray.length > 0 && idArray[1].length > 0) {
                postData(idArray);
            } else {
                alert("Please select at least one record.");
            }
        });

        function postData(idArray) {
            ... ajax call goes here ...
        }
    </script>  
</apex:page>
```

Is it normal I can't use a standardcontroller for Invoice?
The developer docs say there are standard controllers for all queryable objects:

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the API version of the Visualforce page 48 or higher? Invoices were not added as a standard object until the last release [according to the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_invoice.htm). There may be limitations around the object because it requires the Salesforce Order Management license and it is explicitly stated it is only available in Lightning Experience - meaning there may not be a standard controller for them in Visualforce.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't realize this was such a recent addition

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realize that Visualforce pages hava a target api version setting. As @nbrown suggests in his comment, Invoice was only added in api version48 and targetting my page to that version solved my problem.